# mysql select item from yesterday for each article

Tags: mysql, sql

i try select for each article 'yesterday' article - something like yesterday i wrote this...

mysql table art: id int, date datetime, text text...

```
SELECT
art.id, art.text, art.date
FROM art
WHERE
date(art.date)=curdate() -interval 1 day
```

work well, but not for oldest articles (not for every day, increment -interval 1...2..3.. day is not solution

```
date(art.date)-interval 1 day
```

return correct date for article one day back
but

```
WHERE
date(art.date)=date(art.date)-interval 1 day
```

dont return any row
Is possible use construction like this ? Its my mistake ? How big ? :)

I just did workaround, but im courisous for "only mysql" solution.

Comment: Did not understand you mean you need to get data from yesterday and before that ?

Comment: `date(art.date)=date(art.date)-interval 1 day` simply means `2 = 2 - 1`. If a user writes a single articles on a given day then you could  use LIMIT and OFFSET

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of the question.  For any given date, you want the articles from the previous date where there were articles.

```
SELECT art.id, art.text, art.date
FROM art join
     (select max(art.date) as yestdate
      from art
      where art.date <= curdate() -interval 1 day
     ) const
WHERE date(art.date) = yestdate;
```